# is there any tristate type in c++ stl?

Tags: c++, stl

is there any tristate type in c++ stl?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, but there is [boost tribool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/tribool.html).

Comment: tribool is handy, but it always annoyed me that the tribool default constructor constructed an instance with value false, rather than indeterminate.

Comment: Right, that is possibly not the most logical default value. But you can always supply an initial value to the constructor.

Answer (score 7):

You could also use a enumerated type with three values

Answer (score 4):

This site may help =P

http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_.aspx

Answer (score 1):

No, your best bet is probably to define a custom class and overload all operators (operator&& etc).